# Error trying to synchronize geth clique client after shutdown

Tags: synchronization, block, memory-corruption, geth, clique

I'm working with a private network using geth clique clients. Each time a node shut downs, (after a power cut, or just killing the geth process), if a try to put it to work again, the node can't synchronize, shooting a runtime error:

```
ERROR[02-01|17:31:27.234] Impossible reorg, please file an issue   oldnum=11495 oldhash=415d9b…c9aa7c newnum=11495 newhash=415d9b…c9aa7c
TRACE[02-01|17:31:27.236] Findnode failed                          id=b1a7659b8a9da1db failcount=1280  err="RPC timeout"
...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x51163e]

goroutine 305 [running]:
math/big.(*Int).Cmp(0xc44e55ff40, 0x0, 0xbe6c1acfbb42a6ab)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/math/big/int.go:319 +0x2e
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).insertSidechain(0xc430d16000, 0xc44fdef650, 0xc420069400, 0xc420069401, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc44fb119cf, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc44d001320, ...)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:1333 +0x1165
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).insertChain(0xc430d16000, 0xc44ebebd50, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:1139 +0x2ee3
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).InsertChain(0xc430d16000, 0xc44ebebd50, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:1088 +0xc46
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).importBlockResults(0xc4200a2ea0, 0xc44ebebd48, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x19)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:1490 +0x434
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).processFullSyncContent(0xc4200a2ea0, 0x0, 0xc431a27f98)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:1464 +0x79
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).(github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.processFullSyncContent)-fm(0xc400000008, 0x1013570)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:479 +0x2a
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).spawnSync.func1(0xc4200a2ea0, 0xc44f7e6900, 0xc44f5c8280)
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:491 +0x59
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).spawnSync
    /build/ethereum-BgsY40/ethereum-1.8.21+bionic/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:491 +0xaf
```

the only way I found for the node to keep running is to delete the database and have it downloaded again, which obviously is not the best option.

Anyone having the same problem? How do you deal with this?